# confused to use Google Cloud speech API

Tags: android, google-text-to-speech

I need to use speech to text functionality on Android platform.  The language which I am using has no offline version, so there is no need to use of RecognizerIntent. 
Although I am confused to use Google Cloud speech API as it is not free and is alpha version. Is it much accurate than built in speech to text API or do they actually use the same API?

Answer (score 0):

Find the GitHub project

This project will helps you both online and offline

https://github.com/hiteshsahu/Android-TTS-STT